# About some question to switch php version in MacOS

Tags: php, macos, nginx, phpbrew

My system OS is `MacOS10.13`. The default PHP version is `7.1.16`.

I use `phpbrew` to manage the PHP version. And I installed the php5.6.When I use command `phpbrew switch php5.6`. Then I use the command`php -v`

Then it outputs:

```sh
PHP 5.6.30 (cli) (built: May 14 2019 18:30:16)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Then  I use the command`php-fpm -v`

output:

```sh
PHP 7.1.16 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Mar 31 2018 03:00:16)
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

The php version in terminal is php5.6, and in the web, the version is php7.1

The php-fpm default path is in `/usr/sbin`.

When I try to replace the php-fpm, the web page is 404. The nginx `error.log` is in here.

```
2019/05/15 18:35:48 [error] 3125#0: *51 kevent() reported that connect() failed (61: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
2019/05/15 18:35:48 [error] 3125#0: *51 open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.15.12/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
2019/05/15 18:35:48 [error] 3125#0: *51 kevent() reported that connect() failed (61: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
2019/05/15 18:35:48 [error] 3125#0: *51 open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.15.12/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
ailed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
2019/05/15 18:48:03 [error] 3125#0: *64 kevent() reported that connect() failed (61: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
2019/05/15 18:48:03 [error] 3125#0: *64 open() "/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.15.12/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "127.0.0.1:82"
```

I want to use php5.6.